# Put parentheses around year in citation

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I have the following Latex code, where I use biber and chicago style for citations:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate,bibencoding=auto,strict,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\begin{document}

    \cite{Herlocker2004}

    \newpage

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this `bibliography.bib`:

```
@article{Herlocker2004,
author = {Herlocker, Jonathan L. and Konstan, Joseph a. and Terveen, Loren G. and Riedl, John T.},
journal = {ACM Transactions on Information Systems},
month = jan,
number = {1},
pages = {5--53},
title = {{Evaluating collaborative filtering recommender systems}},
volume = {22},
year = {2004}
}
```

This produces

`Herlocker u.a. 2004`

But I want to put the year in brackets, and replace the german `u.a.` with `et al.`, so that it looks like this

`Herlocker et al. (2004)`

Is there any way to format my citations like this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's my suggestion. I added the `natbib` option for `biblatex`. This allows you to use the citation commands `\citep` (whole citation in parentheses) and `\citet` (only the year is in parentheses).
I then redefined the `andothers` bibliography string for German, like so

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  andothers = {et al.},
}
```

I'd recommend you use the command `\addbibresource` in the preamble, instead of `\bibliography` which is legacy (see biblatex manual for v.2.5, p.82).

My suggestion for your working example then becomes

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Herlocker2004,
author = {Herlocker, Jonathan L. and Konstan, Joseph a. and Terveen, Loren G. and Riedl, John T.},
journal = {ACM Transactions on Information Systems},
month = jan,
number = {1},
pages = {5--53},
title = {{Evaluating collaborative filtering recommender systems}},
volume = {22},
year = {2004}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate,bibencoding=auto,strict,backend=biber,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  andothers = {et al.},
}


\selectlanguage{ngerman}


\begin{document}

    \citet{Herlocker2004}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\citet` is just an alias for the standard `biblatex` `\textcite` (with the addition of the starred option), one might add. `\textcite` does not need the `natbib` compatibility mode.

Comment: @moewe `\textcite` worked fine for me with `biblatex`. Seems logical to avoid `natbib` compatibility mode, if I've already chosen `biblatex`? This is also the simplest answer. I now have brackets `()` around the date where I need them. Unless there's a reason *not* to do it this way?

Comment: @DaveEveritt Of course it does. The `natbib` compatibility mode has a few side-effects besides allowing to use `\citet` and `\citep` (you can find the definitions in `blx-natbib.def`): the starred versions of `\cite` commands differ and the delimiter between year and date in `authoryear`-like styles is set to `\addcomma\space`. So I generally don't use it if I don't need `natbib`-like commands. I just commented because I felt that one could take the first few lines in the answer to mean that it is the `natbib`-option that allows us to have parenthetical citations (but there is `\parencite`).

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to wrap the year in brackets and avoiding issues with an ibid style.

Specifying the natbib option and using the citet command (as stated in the accepted answer) doesn't work as expected when using an ibid style.

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\begin{document}

    \cite[21]{keyxyz}
    % outputs: someauthor (2003, p. 21)
   \citet[23]{keyxyz}
    % outputs: someauthor (ibid., p.23) <-- that's fine
   \citet{keyxyz}
    % outputs: someauthor (ibid.) <-- the isssue:
    % what if you want to refer to the authors work as a whole, without
    % referencing the page number as well (as ibid usually implies)?

\end{document}
```

A quick workaround would be:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\citeauthorandyear}[2][]{
   \citeauthor{#2} (\citeyear[#1]{#2})
}

\begin{document}

    \cite[21]{keyxyz}
    % outputs: someauthor (2003, p. 21)
    \citeauthorandyear{keyxyz}
    % outputs: someauthor (2003) <- that's better now
    \citet[22]{keyxyz}
    % outputs: someauthor (ibid., p.22)

\end{document}
```

For more complex rewrites see the biblatex manual p.131, 4.3.1 \DeclareCiteCommand.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about how your posting addresses the OP's issue.

Comment: Maybe `authoryear-ibid` is not for you then, if you dislike "someauthor (ibid.)". Try `authoryear` instead, then the output will exactly resemble that of the workaround.

Comment: @moewe no, ibid is fine in most cases but if i want to refer to the author's work as a whole, ibid is not suitable at that moment, as it also refers to the recently mentioned page number. as i cannot use citet then, i created a command that produces 'author (date)'. please see the updated example.