# Style for biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I need to realize a special style with `biblatex` for cites within a paragraph. The requirements are the following:

- General cite should be last name of first author and year: Smith (2012)
- More pubs in one year with Smith (2012a), Smith (2012b) etc.
- Having two authors, both are mentioned with last name and year: Smith and Paul (2009)
- More than two authors should be Chin et al. (2013)

I would be more than happy to get that realized, since I need to prepare material for students at the present semester.

With the one I tried below, the following issues appeared:

- Cite: the year is not set in parenthesis ("A. Author 2001" instead of "A. Author (2001)")
- Cite: I only would need the last name, like "Author (2001)"
- "`maxcitenames`"seems not to work...
- Bib: Authors should always listed with last name first and initials, like "Author, A. und Author, B. (2001). Alpha." and not "Author, A. und B. Author (2001). Alpha."

Here is what I tried as minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,%
    backend=biber,%
    maxcitenames=2,%
    language=ngerman]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{A01a,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{A01b,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{A01}

\cite{A01a}

\cite{A01b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried, where didn’t it work out? This looks pretty close to the `authoryear` style. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles might be helpful as a start. Please specify your problem and make sure to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) including a bib file with all the necessary test cases (see “Bibliography Files” under the second link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your MWE, the initials were always shown to differentiate between *A. Author* and *B. Author*, who share a last name and must be told apart by their initial. If you change the names, the initials will go away.

The `maxcitenames` problem seems to be related to the duplicate name *Author* as well; if you change the names, the *et al.* works correctly.

To get the year in parentheses, add the option `natbib`, which doesn’t change anything, but only enables more macros. Then, use `\citet{foo}` instead of `\cite{foo}`. (See [Put parentheses around year in citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104518/4012).)

To change the ordering of the names, use:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

(For a detailed explanation see [biblatex - Order last-first for the names of multiple editors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113573/4012).)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,%
    backend=biber,%
    maxcitenames=2,%
    language=ngerman,%
    natbib
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{A02,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Beta},
}

@misc{A01a,
  author = {Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{A01b,
  author = {Duthor, D. and Euthor, E. and Futhor, F.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\begin{document}

\citet{A01}

\citet{A02}

\citet{A01a}

\citet{A01b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]